# The trait Extend is not implemented for Vec when partitioning an iterator

Tags: rust

I am running into the error when calling `.partition()` on a vector iterator:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<std::result::Result<std::collections::HashSet<&std::string::String>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>: std::iter::Extend<&std::result::Result<std::collections::HashSet<std::string::String>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:9:24
  |
9 |         results.iter().partition(|r| r.is_ok());
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::iter::Extend<&std::result::Result<std::collections::HashSet<std::string::String>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<std::result::Result<std::collections::HashSet<&std::string::String>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <std::vec::Vec<T> as std::iter::Extend<&'a T>>
            <std::vec::Vec<T> as std::iter::Extend<T>>
```

When running the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

fn main() {
    let mut results: Vec<Result<HashSet<String>>> = Default::default();

    let (okays, errors): (Vec<Result<HashSet<&String>>>, Vec<_>) =
        results.iter().partition(|r| r.is_ok());
}
```

See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb2ba862e1d4b78cdfbdd3df9a17b4c7) for example.

Comment: Wrong type: `.iter()` gives you an iterator of `&Result<HashSet<_>>`, not an iterator of  `&Result<HashSet<&String>>`. It's best to just let it infer the rest of the type.

Comment: The type specified for `okays` is wrong, it should be `Vec<&Result<HashSet<String>>>` (or alternatively just `Vec<_>`). `results.iter()` returns `impl Iterator<Item=&Result<HashSet<String>>>`.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question — [The trait `rayon::iter::ParallelExtend<impl std::future::Future>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63565121/155423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states (with namespacing removed):

> the trait `Extend<&Result<HashSet<String>, Box<dyn Error>>>` is not implemented for `Vec<Result<HashSet<&String>, Box<dyn Error>>>`

You can't extend a `Vec<T>` with elements of type `&T` because **they aren't the same type**.

Instead, you can do one of these:

1. Change the type of the destination collection to `Vec<&Result<HashSet<String>>>` (or just `Vec<_>`, like your second destination type, to allow the compiler to infer the inner type).
2. Convert the reference to an owned value, perhaps via `clone` or `to_owned`.
3. Don't iterate over references to start with, using `into_iter` or `drain` instead.

However, your current type will be very hard or expensive to achieve, as you state that you want an owned `Result` with an owned `HashMap` but a *reference* the `String`.

I think the best thing is to use [`Itertools::partition_map`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_map) and `into_iter`:

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0
use std::collections::HashSet;

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn main() {
    let mut results: Vec<Result<HashSet<String>>> = Default::default();

    let (errors, okays): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = results.into_iter().partition_map(Into::into);
    // let (errors, okays): (Vec<Error>, Vec<HashSet<String>>)
}
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423)

Comment: Side question, it appears as if I cannot call .reduce() on okays as it is a reference but neither .clone() or .to_owned() work? Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: @Eidolon you can't call `reduce` [because there's no such method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=reduce).